# Azure Service Fabric Request Context

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric, multi-tenant

How can I get the user and the tenant I am working on in stateless service in 
Azure Service Fabric?

I want to know which tenant or user I am currently working on without passing them in each method call.
If I use asp.net core I can use IHttpContextAccessor.Request and IHttpContextAccessor.User to get these values. How can I do it when I am inside 
stateless fabric service?

**UPDATE 17.6.2018** 
Just to clarify what I actually need:
My app is a multi tenant application and I want to avoid sending the tenant id to each method as a parameter all the way down. If there was  something like a request context I could initialize the tenant id in the beginning of the request and use it only in the places where I actually need it like in the data access tier etc.

Answer (score 1):

A service in Service Fabric is just an executable. So if you require user authentication, you'll need to [add that yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-and-service-security). 
For example, you can host [Asp.net Core inside a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore).

Doing this will allow you to use Membership as you're accustomed with, while running inside Service Fabric.

You can also decide to use an API Gateway (e.g. Azure API Management) on top of your cluster and delegate access control to that.